# Use of numWorkers in firebase-queue

Tags: firebase, firebase-queue

I am using `firebase-queue` in a mobile app to handle some server side work. In the `firebase-queue` documentation [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/tree/v1.3.1#queue-worker-options-optional), it says that we can specify an optional parameter `numWorkers` which specifies number of workers that can run simultaneously for the node.js thread. I don't fully understand how to use this parameter in my application. For e.g., one of the thing that I am doing on the server side using `firebase-queue` is to send a verification code to the user when he/she first logs into the application. Now this could be hundreds of users in the future. I have a few questions that I wanted to clarify to understand the user of `numWorkers` a little better

1. When should I have more than one worker for a firebase queue?
2. What is the optimum number of workers for any firebase queue? Coming from a Java background, it's said that having more and more threads running in an application may start to become an overhead after a certain limit. Not sure if similar principles apply here.
3. If I have more than one queue serving different `specIds`, then do I need to think about of number of total workers at cumulative level rather than per queue. I have four queues at the moment.

Please let me know if you have information in regards to my questions above. Any inputs are appreciated.

**Update - June 5, 2016**

After some more playing around with the `firebase-queue`, I have realized that the `numWorkers` controls how many task of a given spec can be running simultaneously. Since the queue worker is not working in an asynchronous fashion, if tasks of a given specId takes a long time to finish, then you may end up with many tasks in the queue waiting to be picked up. For e.g. if there is a network element in the processing of the task, then it may take longer to finish and if you expect a lot of these tasks to be present on the queue, then you should have a more than one worker in the firebase queue. So, I know the answer to my first question now.

I am still wondering about question 2 and 3. I have some tasks in the queue which could be in hundreds or thousands at a given time and some of them involve a network element, so they may take a considerable amount of time to finish. I am not sure of the repercussions of having say hundred workers for a queue. I am not able to test it myself since my app is still in development state and I don't have a setup to simulate a large amount of such tasks at the moment.

Comment: Hi Varun, did you make any discoveries on this since?

Comment: Hi Alan, no new discoveries since my last update.